# Optimizing LINQ Query using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a following LINQ query to get product information using Entity Framework

```
productDetails.Items = (from productDetail in db.ToList()
                            select new prod
                            {
                                ID = productDetail.ID
                            ProdName = productDetail.ProductName,
                                        ...
                                        ...
                                        ...
                                        ...
                            Calaculation1 = GetCalaculation(productDetail.Calc1),
                            Calaculation1 = GetCalaculation(productDetail.Calc2),
                                        ...
                                        ...
                                        ...
                                        ...
                                        Calaculation15 = GetCalaculation(productDetail.Calc3)
                            }
                        ).ToList();
```

where the GetCalaculation method also queries DB using LINQ. The query is slow if I am fetching 100's of records. How I can optimize it?

Comment: I think you would need to show us GetCalaculation() as well.

Comment: Because you're calling `ToList` your query runs in memory, and every single `GetCalculation` method call makes a separate database query. That will definitely not scale.

Comment: Short answer is do not use Entity Framework write direct query or use db.SQLQuery

Comment: Here is the GetCalculation method var dbQuery = (from calculation in db.Calculations
                                   where calculation.calc == calc1
                                   select calculation);
                   
                    totalsum = (from xyz in dbQuery
                              select (Decimal?)xyz.calc).Sum() ?? 0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the structure of your select looks a "little" problematic to me since you fetching 15 `Calaculation` properties for each record. Even if you create a view in the data base it will have 15 `Joins` to Calculations table which is very bad for performance. So the first thing that you should do is to review your object structure and to confirm that you REALLY need all those calculations to be fetched in one request.
If you insist that your structure can not be changed here are some steps that could significantly improve the performance:

1. If the tables don't change to often you may consider to create materialized view (view with clustered index in SQL Server) that will contain already calculated data. In this case the query will be very fast but the Inserts/Updates in to tables will be much slower.
2. Do not use `db.ToList()` in your query - by doing it you fetch all your table in to the memory and then you issue separate queries for each one of the calculations.
3. I am a little confused about this query:

   ```
   var dbQuery = from calculation in db.Calculations 
                 where calculation.calc == calc1 select calculation); 
   var totalsum = (from xyz in dbQuery select (Decimal?)xyz.calc).Sum() ?? 0;
   ```

You are fetching all the records that have a `calc == calc1` and then calculating their sum?  wouldn't it be much easier to count how many records have `calc == calc1` and then to multiply it by `calc1`

```
db.Calculations.Count(c=>c.calc == calc1) * calc1;
```

4. It could be cheaper to fetch all the Calculations table into memory together with Product table ( `var calcTable =  db.Calculations.ToList()` ) if it has a limited number of records then GetCalaculation will work with in-memory objects that will be faster. If you are going to do it you may consider to do it in parallel or in separate Tasks.